# Principal value of 1/x

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

I'm trying to show that p.v.$\frac{1}{x}(\varphi):= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{|x|> \epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x}dx, \varphi \in \mathcal{S}$ exists and defines a tempered distribution, where $\mathcal{S}$ denotes Schwartz space.

First step is I split the integral up:

p.v.$\frac{1}{x}(\varphi) = \int_{|x|<1}\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}dx + \int_{|x|>1} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x}dx$

Now I notice that the first integral on the right hand side is essentially the mean value theorem so is equal to some derivative of $\varphi$.

Question:

- How do i deal with the second integral?
- I know that $\int \frac{1}{x}dx$ is not integrable near the origin due to it have a singularity, so are my steps justified so far and if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question. 
\begin{align*}
\int_{|x|>1}\dfrac{|\varphi(x)|}{x}dx&=\int_{|x|>1}\dfrac{|x\varphi(x)|}{x^{2}}dx\\
&\leq\sup_{x\in{\bf{R}}}|x\varphi(x)|\int_{|x|>1}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}dx\\
&=2\sup_{x\in{\bf{R}}}|x\varphi(x)|.
\end{align*}
Second question. You should write $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}\displaystyle\int_{\epsilon<|x|<1}\dfrac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}dx$. Now we see that 
\begin{align*}
\chi_{\epsilon<|x|<1}\left|\dfrac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}\right|\leq\chi_{|x|<1}\|\varphi'\|_{L^{\infty}({\bf{R}})},
\end{align*}
and $\chi_{|x|<1}\|\varphi'\|_{L^{\infty}({\bf{R}})}\in L^{1}({\bf{R}})$, so Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem applies.

Comment: why is $\chi_{|x|<1}||\varphi'||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})} \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}) $

Comment: That $\|\varphi'\|_{L^{1}({\bf{R}})}$ is a constant, now $\displaystyle\int_{{\bf{R}}}\chi_{|x|<1}dx=v_{n}<\infty$, the volume of the unit ball.

Comment: Where does $\varphi (0)$ come from?

Comment: We know that $\displaystyle\int_{\epsilon<|x|<1}\dfrac{\varphi(0)}{x}dx=0$.

Comment: Why does the limit $\chi_{\epsilon<|x|<1}\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x}$ exist for $\epsilon \to 0$? I mean, why does the pointwise convergence condition in the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem satisfied?

Comment: If $x=0$, then the term is just zero because $0\notin\{\epsilon<|x|<1\}$. If $x\ne 0$, then some $\epsilon>0$ is so small such that $\epsilon<|x|<1$, so the term simply becomes $\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)/x$.

Comment: Of course if $|x|\geq 1$, the term also vanishes.